# Cannot access Sonar TreeMap

Tags: sonarqube, treemap

I am using sonar 3.1.1.

I cant access

> sonar::Treemap.size_metric and sonar::Treemap.color_metric

to display a treemap.

please help me to solve this problem. Or some one suggest an alternative for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sonar::Treemap is not part of our Ruby API (which is api::*), so I would not advise you to use it as it can change without notice.

Comment: Is there any solution to display the treemap ?

Comment: If you want to display a treemap, just define a dashboard and include a treemap widget.

Comment: Is it not a complex one?can you please give an example

Comment: You don't have to implement your own widget, just add the existing treemap widget to your dashboard.

Comment: @SimonBrandhof I dont want to display treemap widget in dashboard
I want to display it in a plugin that I am developing.how can I display it?